# self join data to get distinct years

Tags: pandas

I have this dataframe that I need to join in order to find the academic-years.

```
df11=pd.read_csv('https://s3.amazonaws.com/todel1623/myso.csv')

df11.course_id.value_counts()
274    3
285    2
260    1
```

I can use self-join and get the respective years without any problem.

```
df=df11.merge(df11[['course_id']], on='course_id')

df.course_id.value_counts()
274    9
285    4
260    1
```

But the expected count in this case is

```
274    6
285    4
260    2
```

This is because even if there are 3 years for id 274, the course duration is only 24 months. And even if there is only 1 record for 260 since the duration is 24 months, it should return 2 records. (once for current year and the other current_year + 1), rest of the column values being same for that group.

---

Can I write a loop for dataframe something like this?

```
for row in df:
    if i in range((df.duration_inmonths / 12)):
        df.row.year= df.row.year + i
        df.append(df.row)
```

---

In the following case, the first record should be 2017 and not 2018.

```
myl=list()
for row in df11.values:
    for i in range(int(row[15]/12)):
        row[5]=row[5]+i
        myl.append(row)

myl[:2]

[array([383, 1102, 'C-43049', 'M.B.A./M.M.S.', 'Un-Aided', 2018, 80000,
        8000, 900, 312, 89212, 2018, 12, 260, 95, 24, 1102.0,
        'M.B.A./M.M.S.'], dtype=object),
 array([383, 1102, 'C-43049', 'M.B.A./M.M.S.', 'Un-Aided', 2018, 80000,
        8000, 900, 312, 89212, 2018, 12, 260, 95, 24, 1102.0,
        'M.B.A./M.M.S.'], dtype=object)]
```

Comment: HI, so you're looking to "expand" df11?  eg the first row (course_id=260) would become two rows because of the duration_inmonths = 24?  The same for the three rows of 274 as they would become 6 rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

numpy array do not seem to append in a list with changed values. It worked when I converted it to list.

```
myl.append(row.tolist())
```